# How does AKS handle the .env file in a container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, environment-variables, containers, azure-aks

Assume there is a backend application with a private key stored in a .env file.

For the project file structure:

```
|-App files
|-Dockerfile
|-.env
```

If I run the docker image locally, the application can be reached normally by using a valid public key during the API request. However, if I deploy the container into AKS cluster by using same docker image, the application failed.

I am wondering how the container in a AKS cluster handle the .env file. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You can try adding the private key variables you need as env variables in the kubernetes Deployment/Pod Objects or if you need them secured you can pass them as kubernetes secrets

Comment: What works on docker won't work on kubernetes out of the box. What is the main goal? Transfer public key to the pod with a container? There are several ways to achieve it.

Comment: @VishwasKarale I understood passing as kubernetes secrets is a way. But I would like to find out the reason why it works in docker but not in kubernetes.

Comment: @moonkotte I am new to kubernetes, why would it happen actually? For my case, I would like to transfer my public key within the GET request, then the private key stored in the application will authenticate it and return correct response. If I would like to use a similar way as in docker, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Yuk Chan when you run your docker image your container becomes your environment but when you run your app in kubernetes cluster the Container runs in the Pod and the Pod becomes your environment as it takes higher priority so you will need to add your variables in Pod's environment

Comment: @YukChan For you first question: docker is not a kubernetes, it's different entities. You can find a simple comparison between it [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kubernetes-vs-docker/). Can you please explain exactly your task (edit your question) so it will be possible to answer correctly? I don't really understand about get request. What prevents container in pod to perform it.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Hi, finally I use kubernetes secret to pass credentials into the pod, coz I cannot find another way to work on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this out of comments for better visibility.

---

First and most important is docker is not the same as kubernetes. What works on docker, won't work directly on kubernetes. Docker is a container runtime, while kubernetes is a container orchestration tool which sits on top of docker (not always docker now, `containerd` is used as well).

There are many resources on the internet which describe the key difference. For example this one is from [microsoft docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kubernetes-vs-docker/)

---

First `configmaps` and `secrets` should be created:

[Creating and managing configmaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-a-configmap) and [creating and managing secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#creating-a-secret)

There are different types of [secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#secret-types) which can be created.

---

1. Use configmaps/secrets as environment variables.

Further referring to `configMaps` and `secrets` as `environment variables` looks like (configmaps and secrets have the same structure):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata: 
  name: pod-example
spec: 
  containers: 
    - ...
      env: 
        - 
          name: ADMIN_PASS
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef: # here secretref is used for sensitive data
              key: admin
              name: admin-password
        - 
          name: MYSQL_DB_STRING
          valueFrom: 
            configMapKeyRef: # this is not sensitive data so can be used configmap
              key: db_config
              name: connection_string
      ...
```

2. Use configmaps/secrets as volumes (it will be presented as file).

Below the example of using secrets as files mounted in a specific directory:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
...
    spec:
      containers:
      - ...
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets-files
          mountPath: "/mnt/secret.file1"  # "secret.file1" file will be created in "/mnt" directory
          subPath: secret.file1
      volumes:
        - name: secrets-files
          secret:
            secretName: my-secret # name of the Secret
```

There's a [good article](https://medium.com/avmconsulting-blog/secrets-management-in-kubernetes-378cbf8171d0) which explains and shows use cases of secrets as well as its limitations e.g. size is limited to 1Mb.